# How do you curate the content that you want to read?

Tags: discussion

I'm interested in understanding how the more regular users (who don't come here through web searches anymore $-$ or at least not as often) use this website.

The notion of a feed on stackexchange websites is very different from the modern social networking type of Q&A sites. So, how do you select questions and answers you want to read about?

How can I, as a user, curate my experience in a way that makes it possible to read more high quality content?

Comment: This older post seems related: [What can users do to improve their Math.SE experience?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8626)

Comment: Checking in with [Pearl Dive](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102837/pearl-dive) regularly can be helpful for finding good content.

Comment: The set of watched and ignored tags already gives me a desired list. And sort the list using active or unanswered

Comment: Also its only a matter of time before you get addicted. Then you will automatically get the content which matters most to you here.

Comment: For years I've just scrolled through the new questions; never had any problem finding interesting stuff.

Comment: Heh - the site is usually fast enough that scrolling through it is not painful - like we don't get long delays waiting for the next page...

Answer (score 4):

You can choose any tag and include it in your "Watched tags" list. That's the way I usually browse the site. I click on my list of tags to see the new questions. Most of the time I keep the questions ordered by "newest", and from time to time I look at "active" (not really sure what it does exactly), "bountied", "unanwered", and "votes" (the most voted questions are often interesting, often fairly old).

You can also manage your "ignored tags" list if it suits you.

Comment: Re: *I look at "active" (not really sure what it does exactly)*. The active tab shows the questions ordered by the recent activity. I.e., you can see the questions which recently had new answer, were edited or were [bumped](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bumping/info) for some other reason. (You can also see the type of activity, such as "answered 5 mins ago user1234" or "modified 10 mins ago user4313".)

Comment: Also to the suggestion looking at the watched tag I will add that it is easy to created a custom filter for those tags - to have quickly accessible a link which only shows questions in those tags. Slightly less comfortable solution is to user "intags:mine" in the search field. More details can be found in the answers to this question: [Can we have a feed of watched tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29530).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: thanks for intags:mine this is so much better than clicking all watched tags one by one.

Comment: I just bookmark https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aq for the newest questions in my tags and use that almost exclusively.